# Asking for issues experienced with ASP.net MVC during an interview

Tags: asp.net-mvc, orm

After speaking with a colleague regarding interview questions I am compiling, the subject was raised of asking about

"Can you go into any detail of any issues you have experienced with ASP.Net MVC/ORMs and how you resolved them?"

This is based on the assumption that pretty much everyone has had a issue with MVC (Dropdown lists...) and ORMs.

Does this sound like a suitable interview question?

Thanks,

Comment: Yes, this is true! Question edited, to apply to ASP.Net MVC.

Comment: Refer this
http://grandhah.blogspot.in/2015/08/mvc-interview-questions.html